# Display rows from another sheet's table

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a Sheet1 with 2 columns A2:A200 where A1 is labeled TASK, and B2:B200 where B1 is labaled DATE. I want to take all tasks from Sheet1 with today's date and display them in a Sheet2.

I've tried using IF and VLOOKUP, but failed. Maybe i didn't do it right

Comment: May be `FILTER()` you need. `VLOOKUP()` will only bring the first instances of `TODAY()` date records. For multiple use either `FILTER()` if using `MS365` else use `INDEX()`+`AGGREGATE()`

Answer (score 0):

This formula will produce a spill formula output of all the tasks (and dates) for today's date. You can also substitute the today formula to a cell input with the date you want to filter for if you prefer that.

`=FILTER(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$200,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$200=TODAY())`

If you only want a list of the tasks for today, but don't need the second column you can adjust it to the following:

`=CHOOSECOLS(FILTER(Sheet1!$A$1:$B$200,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$200=TODAY()),1)`

You can also add a `Sort` formula around this if you need it in a particular order of tasks.

If you don't have 365, you can select the table and insert a pivot table, bringing the tasks to the bottom left pane and the date to filter range and select the date to filter for. You can make the pivot table a tabular view (under the design tab in the ribbon) and filter the date to just be for today's date so it shows all the tasks for that date and it will refresh accordingly. If you use a table format you can avoid re-defining the table range and the re-selecting the date filter.